# HTML Form $_POST does not work

Tags: php, html

**menus.php**

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mmogezgini");
$menuler = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM menuler");
while($menu = mysqli_fetch_array($menuler)) {
   $isim = $menu["isim"];
   $url = $menu["url"];
?>
<form method="post">
    Menü İsmi :<input name="menu_isim" value="<?php echo $isim; ?>" disabled> | 
    Menü URL : <input name="menu_url" value="<?php echo $url;?>"disabled> 
    <button type="submit" formmethod="post" formaction="menu_duzenle.php">Düzenle</button>
    <button formaction="menu_sil.php">Sil</button>
</form>
<br>
<?php
 }
?>
```

**edit_menu.php**

```
<form method="post" action="menu_duzenle_islem.php">
Şuanki İsim : <input name="menu_isim" value="<?php echo $_POST['menu_isim'] ?>"disabled>
Yeni İsim : <input name="yeni_menu_isim" placeholder="yeni menü ismini giriniz.">
</form>
```

My Problem is form in *menus.php* wont send `$_POST['menu_isim']` to *edit_menu.php*.need more to write for details

Comment: edit_menu.php = menu_duzenle.php

Comment: You haven't specified a type on that input. `type="text"`

Comment: you dont have a form `action` attribute in the menus.php script, you need it set to `edit_menus.php`

Comment: The input is `disabled`. So it won't be passed.

Comment: @diggersworld `text` is default, you don't have to specify that.

Comment: @Kolink: ah cheers for the info... it's still best in my opinion to include it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabled inputs are not considered "valid" for being passed through a form.

To make an input read-only, use the `readonly` attribute instead.

Keep in mind, however, that this kind of thing CANNOT be trusted. You should save the value in a `$_SESSION` variable and retrieve it from there.

Comment: Thank you problem solved now i will search for save the value in a $_SESSION variable.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the `disabled` attribute. If you want the user not to edit the `input` use `readonly` attribute.